# Checking if element contains specific text on load and on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an element that I do not know if it is controlled by the database or by jquery, **the contents of this element change dynamically**. If the contents of this element are "Review Configuration" I'd like to show an alert box. Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  if ($('a.page_button:contains("Review Configuration")').length > 0) {
    $(".page_button").addClass("thisClass");
  } 
});
```

The page I'm trying to get this to work on is: https://www.bagnboxman.co.uk/product/clear-oval-boxes

the reason for this is that when adding the components of this product to your cart - I am having customers who do not see that they have to click the "Review Configuration" button, and that they then have to click the "add to cart" button. I need to make it blindingly obvious so as not to lose any more sales.

Comment: The code should work assuming the elements are in the DOM when the code runs, and also that they contain the text - which none of the `a.page_button` elements in the example URL you posted do.

Comment: Thanks Rory. The text of this element changes on "the next step" so if you look at that url again, change the quantity of the product, and go to the next step (click clear sleeve), you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I can only see two places where it says 'the next step' in your page and neither of them are links to anything. You'd get much more accurate answers more quickly if you included the relevant parts of the HTML in the question

Comment: the text of this link is "clear sleeve (pt2)" - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into this neat plug-in that will help or you could use the setinterval() function to check every # of milliseconds.

Check out this:
[Constantly checks for a specific element to change then applies your code if it meets the requirements](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-watch)

Otherwise you could use the setInterval() like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  if ($('a.page_button:contains("Review Configuration")').length > 0) {
    $(".page_button").addClass("thisClass");
  }
},1000);
```

Another option so they will be forced to use the "Review Configuration" button would be by using the .trigger('click') so it will automatically click it when it detects the change or whatever.

It would be something like this:

```
$('a.page_button:contains("Review Configuration")').trigger('click');
```

You could also include the `alert("Please Click Review Configuration to add to Cart!");` when the script detects the items or whatever.